# Python function not running

Tags: python, function

```
import math 
import sys 
import random
import __main__

print "Home Temp Assist"
print "Loading......."
print "Testing Pro Type 1 What is your Temp???"

user_input = input()

on = 1 
off = 0
auto = True
a_c = (on, off, auto)
temp = "user_input"

heat = (on, off)

print "Temperature is measured in Degrees F"
set_temp = range(60, 100)
print "you are here [1]"
def Turn_On(n):
    Heat = 1
    print "your Heat is on"

def Room_Temp(n):
    if temp < 75:
        Turn_On = True
        set_temp = 75
        print "Your Temperature has been set to 75"
    else:
        Temp < 75 
        print "Room needs to cool down"

print " you are here [2] "



def Turn_Off(n):
    Heat = 0 
    Fan = 0

print "you are here [3]"
```

I am having trouble with my `Room_Temp` function.  When I run the code and enter a temp nothing happens.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You're never calling the function `Room_Temp`, so that block of code is never run

Comment: You also need to be careful with overriding functions with variables: `Turn_On = True` can lead to great confusion when you want to call the `Turn_On` function a few lines later. Remember, in Python functions are first-class, meaning that `def Turn_On():` is basically the same as `Turn_On = def():`. You possible intended to use `Turn_On(True)`? Also, `Temp < 75` like that does nothing; if seems you're missing an `if`?

Comment: Above the line `print "you are here [2]"` put a new line line `Room_Temp(user_input)` and see what the output says when you run it. (This is what @mhlester means by "calling the function"). Then you'll also see the relation between that and what @carpetsmoker says about Turn_On...

Comment: All in all, it looks like you're having trouble understanding basic Python syntax and structure. While I'm all for experimenting,  I would **strongly** recommend reading up on basic Python; the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is a good place to start, although I would personally recommend Mark Lutz's *[Learning Python](http://learning-python.com/books/about-lp.html)*, as it's much more in-depth and explains things better (but it's not free). We all struggled when learning this—so that's normal, and don't give up hope or stop experimenting!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You also never defined the value 'n' which you are using in your define functions
def Room_Temp(n):
The value 'n' is not defined.

Comment: if i change n to user_input then how do i call the function

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The function isn't even called.